# Why was Data built with the capability to be intimate with a woman?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, robots, sexuality

Pardon the inherent ickiness of asking how an android and a human...become intimate, but this has genuinely puzzled me since I watched the Next Generation episode "[The Naked Now](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Naked_Now_%28episode%29)." The summary for the episode on Memory Alpha states:

> She asks how "functional" Data is; he replies he is fully functional and is programmed in many "techniques," a wide variety of pleasuring. She leads him to her bedroom, where Data gives a programmed smile. The door closes.

I'm not asking for specific details because, honestly, ick-factor, but:

- What does "fully functional" really mean?
- Why was Data built to perform a "wide variety of pleasuring"?

Comment: Is your question "how intimate were they" or "why is Data programmed for this"?

Comment: Good question. I'd say the latter, because it's less icky. Revising!

Comment: Please make the edit summary "made less icky".

Comment: [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/StarTrekTheNextGeneration) has this listed: "The night with Data. He agrees to keep it quiet, but we see that it's one of his most precious memories. (In an extended version of Yar's goodbye message, she says, "Data? It did happen.")" The same page also points out that Data's ridiculous humanoidness is because, "His creator was far more interested in the puzzle of creating fully-sentient mechanical life than any commercial applications."

Comment: @Abby - done :)

Comment: I'm wondering how many times Brett's gonna say icky in this question.

Comment: My guess would be, that Dr. Soong intends to someday download *himself* into an android body... :)

Comment: I find nothing about this topic Icky. Me Gusta.

Comment: Vote yes on proposition ∞

Comment: If mods will permit, I will point that there is even a quite good song about this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlbmi1hhV_0

Comment: You know how it is.  You've dedicated yourself to this huge complicated project ("build an android") and you can't figure out how to solve this one really tricky part ("give him emotions without making him a serial killer"), so you procrastinate by solving relatively simple problems ("make his junk work") instead.

Comment: Out of universe, Star Trek is bubbling over with sexual motivations, it's rare to find an entity you can't screw, and if you do you it's full-on inconceivable Lovecraftian horror.

Comment: Data is fully functional, but can't say contractions? WTF!?

Comment: The whole episode is out of character for Data. The polywater shouldn't really affect him, and he acts nervous when Tasha seduces him which is an emotion he is later shown as incapable of experiencing.

Comment: John C may be right, but look at cutting edge robots today and how many of them are suped up love dolls? It's not inconceivable that he was built specifically as a fuck-bot.

Comment: Moreover, if he's "fully functional," does that mean he has a seminal tank that needs periodic refilling? If so, you know at some point he's having it filled at a replicator and has one of his classic awkward Data encounters when someone asks what he's up to. Listen, if they didn't want us discussing these intricacies, they wouldn't have written such a weird thing that into the episode. Hell, the whole episode is just weird, why do the men get aggressive, but the women get horny?

Comment: @RubelliteFae I would assume that rather than refilling some specific tank with some specific substance, he ingests some innocuous raw material from which he internally manufactures/replenishes various consumables. In "Deja Q" he tells Q that he occasionally ingests "a semi-organic nutrient suspension in a silicone-based liquid medium".

Comment: A fully functional android from the Questor Tapes mentioned at 20 min mark on Inside Star Trek album 1976 https://youtu.be/SUtMz3dniFU?si=inHP3k6MLGuck9iH

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is addressed again:

From Wikipedia,

> Although stories about Yar are not normally connected to Data, the issue of Data's sexual encounter with Yar amid a ship-wide intoxication during the episode "The Naked Now" is recounted in stories about Data. Data carries a hologram of Yar with him and during the trial regarding his rights in the second season episode "The Measure of a Man," he admitted to the incident with the words "We were intimate."
>   
> <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tasha_Yar&oldid=446752431#Story_overview)</sub>

As far as *why* he was built in this way, Dr. Soong made sure everything else worked (hair growing, et cetera), it makes sense that he would also supply Data with his own "special purpose."

It's also possible that it's part of Dr. Soong's attempt to make an android so realistic that he does not know he's an android, as referenced in the Season 7 episode "Inheritance."

Comment: Sub-question: In Star Trek: First Contact, the Borg Queen comes on to Data and asks him when the last time he was intimate and he states how long it has been for him - is he referring to Tasha Yar?

Comment: @Katey - this is worth a post as a separate Q.

Comment: The thing I don't get is, all that programming, and he can't program Data to whistle?

Comment: Or use contractions. :)

Comment: @RobertF which he then proceeds to use abundantly in many episodes. Seriously, there's a YouTube video showing a clips of times Data has used a contraction and it's minutes long.

Comment: Nice use of “special purpose”.  You clearly know shit from shinola.

Comment: Out of universe, is it certain that the idea about a "Dr. Soong" was already present at the time "The Naked Now" was made? I have asked [a separate question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266159/at-what-point-was-it-decided-that-data-was-built-by-a-human) on this.

Answer (score 3):

I'd have to say, in my opinion, it's assumed he was made to be very life like with all his capabilities; looks, adaptations, mental awareness, that it's not so hard to believe he'd also be equipped with physical functions (fully functional body, sexually) as a normal human being would, or at least a robot/android would. Who's to say Dr. Soong didn't want his android to be a fully functional human being, why not? The question would more or less be, why was he not comprised of more of an emotional awareness? Well that's what his first design was to be, Lore. So, in that respect he scaled down with Data, because Lore was just 'too humanlike'.

Comment: Everything but the skin tone. Speaking of Lore, if Data was designed to be less frightening to humans than Lore, why did Soong think it essential to leave in the sexy bits?

Comment: Why would leaving in the sexy bits make him more frightening?

Comment: My question is, if Soong was going to make Data sexually functional, why did he make him male?  His android wife could be programmed not to object.