# What happened in Tasha Yar's bedroom?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Data being intimate with Tasha Yar - why was Data built with this capability?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5655/data-being-intimate-with-tasha-yar-why-was-data-built-with-this-capability)

When the crew of the Enterprise is infected with the polywater intoxication in "[The Naked Now](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Naked_Now_(episode))," the crew begins behaving strangely. Even Data is not immune to this infection, as he appears responsive to Tasha Yar's seduction. At one point in the episode, she beckons him into her bedroom, he smiles, and the door closes. Are we to believe that they had intercourse?

Comment: @Izkata That could mean many things. Perhaps she simply wanted to play cards and wondered if he would be able to deal with concepts like bluffing.

Comment: @Izkata and this is not a duplicate. That other question assumes that intimacy took place. I am seeking to establish whether it did.

Comment: Take a look at the question _and_ answer there.  The current title doesn't quite match (the original does), but the content does answer this question...

Comment: Ok I don't really understand but I won't be upset if you close as duplicate. I have more questions :)

Comment: @Annie - the general rule on duplicates is that if answer to Q2 answers Q1, they are duplicates even if questions themselves are different. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @Annie It may not be; it takes either a mod (someone with a ♦ next to their name, which I am not), or 4 other users to agree with me before it gets closed

Comment: I know the question's 3 years old, but I had to give it a +1 for the title alone.

Answer (score 12):

In the episode "The Measure of a Man" Data states explicitly that he and Tasha were intimate.  Excerpt from the hearing to determine whether Data was the property of Starfleet:

> PICARD: And this?  You have no other portraits of your fellow crewmembers.  [Looks toward hologram of Tasha Yar] Why this person?
>
> DATA: I would rather not answer that question, sir.  I gave my word.
>
> PICARD: Under the circumstances I don't think Tasha would mind.
>
> DATA: She was special to me sir.  We were... intimate.

At the time of the intimacy, Tasha was out of uniform and wearing a provocative outfit.  She responded with delight when Data stated that he was "programmed in multiple techniques, a broad variety of pleasuring," and dragged him off to her bedroom.  They had sex, no doubt.